# Error comming on maketext in toast

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

```
public void onClick(View v) {


        {


            if (db==null) db = new DB(AddStation.this);
            if(v.getId()==R.id.ADD ) {
                String code = Scode.getText().toString().trim();
                String name = SName.getText().toString().trim();
                String fac = SFac.getText().toString().trim();
                if(name.equals("")){
                    Scode.setError("Invalid name");
                    return;
                }

                if (code.equals("")){ Scode.setError("Invalid email");
                    return;
                }
                    if (db.addStudent(code, name, fac))
                        Toast.makeText(AddStation.this, "Student added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                else if (v.getId()==R.id.See) {
                Toast.makeText(AddStation.this, db.getAllStudents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Log.v("EditText", db.getAllStudents().toString());

                    }
                }

                }
            db.close();
            Toast.makeText(AddStation.this, db.getAllStudents(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
```

AddStation is my Fragment name. how to solve this ?
this toast is retriving database and can u guys tell me how to bring data into a dropdown box  or gridview instead of a toast. thanks!

Comment: Do you have a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`?

Comment: yup i do. the database where the query is select this from this table

Comment: Can u see the question again i changed it. thanks!

Comment: You are getting the data required but it is getting displayed in Toast?

Comment: Yahi am gettinng the data required in toast but how to bring that data inside a list view or dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the last two lines. First you called `db.close();`, then called `db.getAllStudents()`, so ARE YOU KIDDING? 
But if not this caused error, then post you `logcat trace`

PS:check your `AddStation`, is it extended from `Activity` or its descendants? If not, extend your `AddStation` from `Activity` or its descendants.

Comment: First on DB(AddStation.this) is saying "The constructor DB(AddStation) is undefined" and on toast.maketext this saying "The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (AddStation, String, int)"

Answer (score 0):

You can display this data in List/Spinner, for this you had to add these widgets in your layout. You can populate this data as
1. ListView

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
List<String> listRecords = db.getAllStudents();
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item, listRecords);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

2. Spinner

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
List<String> listRecords = db.getAllStudents();
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listRecords);
spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```